# Como pasar parámetros del model al jsp y como hacer un for en jsp para pintar componentes <a/>?

Tags: java, jsp, spring

Tengo el siguiente código en mi controller, en el objeto **menu** recupero las rutas a las que tiene derecho el usuario, quiero pintar esas rutas en el jsp, pero de modo de hipervinculos  con imágenes, actualmente mi jsp esta de la siguiente manera

```html
@GetMapping(value="/validaUsuario", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public void mostrarValidacion(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
  String redireccion = "/salida";
  try{
   Usuario usuario= service.obtenerRol(request.getRemoteUser());
   
   if(!utileria.validaNulo(user)){
    List<Pagina> pag = service.redireccionn(usuario.getClave(), usuario.getRol());
    redireccion = pag.get(0).getRuta();
    
    MenuPagina menu = servicio.obtenerMenus(pag.get(0).getCvePagina());
    
   }else{
    redireccion = "/salida";
   }
   response.sendRedirect(redireccion);
  }catch(IOException e){
   logger.error("IOException", e);
  }
  
 }
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
   <div class=""slick-carousel>
    <a href="alta" class="CarrouselMenu_ThumbContainer">
     <div class="Icon">
      <img class="IconImgMenu" src="../webResources/img/alta.png" alt="icon_menu">
     </div>
     <div class="CarrouselMenu_Title"> ALTA</div>
    </a>
    
    <a href="baja" class="CarrouselMenu_ThumbContainer">
     <div class="Icon">
      <img class="IconImgMenu" src="../webResources/img/baja.png" alt="icon_menu">
     </div>
     <div class="CarrouselMenu_Title"> BAJA</div>
    </a>
    
    <a href="consulta" class="CarrouselMenu_ThumbContainer">
     <div class="Icon">
      <img class="IconImgMenu" src="../webResources/img/consulta.png" alt="icon_menu">
     </div>
     <div class="CarrouselMenu_Title"> CONSULTA</div>
    </a>
   </div>
  
  </div>
 </section>
```

tengo todos esos hipervinculos en mi jsp de manera estática, ahora lo que quiero hacer es que sea dinámico, que se pinten dependiendo de las rutas que me devuelve el servicio, tal vez devuelva solo 1, o quizá hasta 5 rutas para ponerlas como submenus

Agregue un objeto model en el método del controlador y puse lo siguiente

```html
MenuPagina menu = servicio.obtenerMenus(pag.get(0).getCvePagina());
model.addAtribute("rutas", menu.getChRuta());
```

y en el jsp puse el **href="${rutas}"**  pero no hace nada, entonces lo cambie por **href="@{rutas}"** y si me redirecciona pero no se muestra la pagina y si existe

```html
 <section>
  <div class="container">
   <div class=""slick-carousel>
    <a href="${rutas}" class="CarrouselMenu_ThumbContainer">
     <div class="Icon">
      <img class="IconImgMenu" src="../webResources/img/alta.png" alt="icon_menu">
     </div>
     <div class="CarrouselMenu_Title"> ALTA</div>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Alguien sabe como es la manera correcta de mandar los parámetros al jsp?
y como se haría un for o algún ciclo para que me pinten los demás hipervinculos si es que el servicio me devuelve mas de 1 ruta, gracias

Comment: He visto que has creado otro post, este es mas completo. Por favor borra el otro así no habrá duplicados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer pasando un atributo al `model` como haces o también a la `request`.

Con `JSTL` o directamente con `JAVA` en el `JSP`

---

### [JSTL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)

Necesitaras tener "instalada" una libreria `JSTL`

Y referenciarla en cada `JSP`:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="/RUTA/de-la/libreria"%>
```

**Model Attribute**

```
MenuPagina menu = servicio.obtenerMenus(pag.get(0).getCvePagina());
model.addAtribute("rutas", menu.getChRuta());
```

y lo pintas así:

```
<a href="${rutas}" class="CarrouselMenu_ThumbContainer">
    ...
</a>
```

Esto es correcto, pero ¿que le estas pasando en este atributo? Si le pasas una ruta estará bien, pero si `menu.getChRuta()` devuelve un conjunto de rutas ya sea un `array` o un `arraylist` la manera de pintarlo será diferente:

```
<c:forEach items="${rutas}" var="ruta">
    <a href="${ruta}"> <!-- ${ruta.atributoObjeto}  Si fuese un objeto y quieres acceder a algo en concreto -->
        ...
    </a>
</c:forEach>
```

**Request Attribute**

```
MenuPagina menu = servicio.obtenerMenus(pag.get(0).getCvePagina());
request.setAtribute("rutas", menu.getChRuta());
```

Para pintarlo puedes usar

```
${rutas}
```

O el `scope` especifico de la `request`:

```
${requestScope.rutas}
```

Del mismo modo si es un `array` o un `arraylist`:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.rutas}" var="ruta">
    <a href="${ruta}"> <!-- ${ruta.atributoObjeto}  Si fuese un objeto y quieres acceder a algo en concreto -->
        ...
    </a>
</c:forEach>
```

---

### Java

Si prefieres, lo puedes hacer al estilo phpero, y usar `JAVA`en el `JSP`.

Abriendo las llaves `<% %>`

```
<%
String rutas = (String) request.getAttribute("rutas"); //Yo lo suelo castear al tipo que sea.
%>
```

Y para pintarlo, <%**=** %>:

```
<a href="<%=rutas%>" class="CarrouselMenu_ThumbContainer">
    ...
</a>
```

Si es un `ArrayList`:

```
<%
List<Ruta> listaRutas = (List<Ruta>) request.getAttribute("rutas"); //Yo lo suelo castear al tipo que sea.
for (Ruta ruta: listaRutas ) {
%>
    ...
    <a href="<%=ruta%>" class="CarrouselMenu_ThumbContainer">
        ...
    </a>
    ...
<% 
}
%>
```

---

Relacionado:

[Difference between request.setAttribute and model.addAttribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497744/spring-difference-between-request-setattribute-and-model-addattribute)

Comment: Ya probé todas las formas que me pusiste y  ninguna reconoce lo que traigo del servicio, hay alguna otra configuración que se haga en el jsp?

Comment: Cuando hago click en mi imagen para redireccionar a la ruta que le estoy pasando,  en el navegador  solo    muestra  /admin/%7Bruta%7D  por eso digo que no le está llegando el dato o me falta configurar otra cosa

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar un poco mas? ¿Que te pinta en el href el `${rutas}`? ¿Has probado el atributo del request en vez del model?, ¿Podrías actualizar en la pregunta el método del controller entero para ver si estas haciendo algo mal? Te recomiendo mirarte la siguiente pregunta, ya que si lo sigues haciendo con `sendRedirect` perderás los atributos. [Request Attributes not available in jsp page when using sendRedirect from a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351107/request-attributes-not-available-in-jsp-page-when-using-sendredirect-from-a-serv)

Comment: Si probé con model y el request y no funciona, en la consola del navegador el href sale vacío , revisare  tu link,gracias