# Deshabilitar etiquetas en html para que no sean vistas en el frontend

Tags: java, jsp

Estoy realizando un sistema donde van a ingresar varios usuarios con roles diferentes y necesito deshabilitar divs o etiquetas `<a>` para usuarios no admin.
Por el momento lo estoy realizando enviando un `request.setAttribute` al html desde un servlet envío etiquetas `<!-- aca lo que deshabilito -->` para que no sean visibles.
No estoy segura si existe otra manera de hacer esto o si sirve como lo hago seria una buena practica ?? 
Actualmente lo realizo de esta manera.

```
if (usuario.getRol() > 2) {
    //Estas etiquetas se envian al html para comentar botones o divs a los que 
    // un usuario no admin no deben ingresar
    msj.setAbre("<!--");
    request.setAttribute("abre", msj);

    msj.setCierre("-->");
    request.setAttribute("cierre", msj);
}
```

Comment: Hola @Angelita Creo que en el controlador que responde al request, con independencia de cual sea su naturaleza puedes dividir a preparadores de salida por rol de modo que obtengas facilmente lo que necesitas sin contaminar ni exponer información que no deba ser vista por usuarios sin privilegios suficientes.

Comment: Hola @quevedo , no te entiendo muy exactamente a que te refieres con preparadores de salida ??
Te dare un ejemplo de como lo hago actualmente en la edicion de mi pregunta.

Comment: Meter algo en comentarios de HTML lo deja visible a quien abra el inspector, te recomiendo pienses en otra cosa

Comment: Y como que otra cosa podría ser ?? se me ocurre es crear otros jsp que tengan las etiquetas <a> , y un div contenedor y con un ''' jsp:include ''' en las páginas heredé los jsp que contienen los div que debe usar un usuario admin

Comment: Hola @Angelita por la estructura de tu pregunta no es posible una respuesta específica. De ahí las sugerencias. En tu request (si puedes modificar su código) o, antes de invocarlo puedes hacer un switch para separar por rol las solicitudes entrantes y dirigirlas a bloques de código que preparan salidas específicas por cada rol. Si presentas algo más de código quizás se pueda indicarte algo más concreto al respecto.

Comment: En vez de enviar por atributo `<!-- -->` puedes enviar el rol y en el `jsp` hacer la comprobación para saber que pintar y que no: `<% if(request.getAttribute("rol")>2){%><!-- Código HTML que solo se pintara si el rol es mayor a 2--><%}%>`, échale un ojo a [Como pasar parámetros del model al jsp y como hacer un for en jsp para pintar elementos?
](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290614/como-pasar-par%C3%A1metros-del-model-al-jsp-y-como-hacer-un-for-en-jsp-para-pintar-co/290654#290654)